# Запуск QTimer в основном и отдельном потоке

Tags: c++, многопоточность, qt5

В Qt приложении пи запуске таймеров и в основном и в отдельном потоке, программа падает. Можно ли это делать и как сделать корректно?

Падает при нескольких поочердных срабатываниях таймеров с такой ошибкой:

> ASSERT: "bytes <= bufferSize" in file tools\qringbuffer.cpp, line 74

```
Текст программы:
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainObject* mObject=new MainObject();
    QThread* tThread=new QThread;
    SecondObject* sObject=new SecondObject();
    QObject::connect(tThread, SIGNAL(started()) , sObject, SLOT(startTimer()));
    sObject->moveToThread(tThread);
    tThread->start();
    return a.exec();
}

MainObject::MainObject(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    mTimer=new QTimer(this);
    connect(mTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(mSlot()));
    mTimer->start(500);
    qDebug()<<"this->thread="<<this->thread()<<"mTimer->thread()="<<mTimer->thread();
}

void MainObject::mSlot()
{
    qDebug()<<"this->thread="<<this->thread();
}

SecondObject::SecondObject(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug()<<"this->thread="<<this->thread();
}

void SecondObject::sSlot()
{
    qDebug()<<"thread="<<this->thread();
}

void SecondObject::startTimer()
{
    QTimer* sTimer=new QTimer(this);
    qDebug()<<"this->thread="<<this->thread()<<"sTimer->thread()="<<sTimer->thread();

    connect(sTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(sSlot()));
    sTimer->start(1000);
}
```

Comment: А в каком месте падает?

Comment: а можно пример кода где падает7?

Comment: ну так запускать таймер в потоке нужно правильно. Вполне возможно, что таймер все тики отрабатывает в основном.

Comment: В отладке выводит, что каждый таймер в своем потоке

Comment: @Unick Падает при нескольких поочердных срабатываниях таймеров с такой ошибкой:
 ASSERT: "bytes <= bufferSize" in file tools\qringbuffer.cpp, line 74

Comment: @Alex.B Падает при нескольких поочердных срабатываниях таймеров с такой ошибкой: ASSERT: "bytes <= bufferSize" in file tools\qringbuffer.cpp, line 74

Comment: @KoVadim В отладке выводит, что каждый таймер в своем потоке ...

Comment: @Q85, а вы можете привести весь callstack при креше?

Comment: @Unick 1 1 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint                       0x77060a61 
2 ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin                  0x7709a689 
3 ??                                        0x3d6e4894 
4 ntdll!DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakin             0x7709a650 
5 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk              0x76f38654 
6 ntdll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath   0x77054a77 
7 ntdll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath   0x77054a47 
8 ??

Comment: Возможно проблема в цикле обработи сообщений отдельного треда. Посмотрите вот это, может быть поможет решить проблему: https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects

Comment: @Unick, спасибо, я уже читала эту статью. К сожалению проблему она не помогла решить.

Comment: Вопрос решен, проблема была в записи лога в файл. Писался из двух потоков, в этом и проблема была